# Graphql subscription with multithreaded nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am trying to create a graphql subscription service in a multi-threaded architecture.

If I, for example, create a subscription like below

```
const SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC = 'something_changed';

export const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    somethingChanged: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator(SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC),
    },
  },
}
```

and have multiple instances of identical `nodeJS` server running on my docker cluster, I do not want each of the instances to send subscription event to the client every time new subscription publishing has been made. I only want one (of course preferrably load balanced among the clusters) to be responsible for sending subscription to the client.

Only way I can think of doing this right now is to create an isolated server that is in charge of subscription event and only receive subscription event from a single source as a client. But same multi-threading problem I have mentioned above occurs if I spread out the load of the subscription-responsible servers.

How do I make sure that I only send out single subscription event to the client when there are multi-threade nodeJS backend? Is it only possible with the client side filtering? i.e. ignore events that have already arrived - However I think this is a terrible waste of resource as subscription grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use Redis as a PubSub, that way you have "one source of truth".  i.e. https://github.com/tomyitav/redis-messaging-manager.

I'm sure there are plenty of other libraries that do something similar

Comment: I could use redis but subscription to redis pubsub would also be threaded wouldn't it? So say if an instance of nodeJS server publishes an event, all the other nodeJS servers that have subscribed to it would be subscribed to the event publication and they will simultaneously try to pass event to the client

Comment: Ah, I was misunderstanding.  But, in that case, wouldn't only one instance of the nodeJS servers have the client actively "listening"?  He wouldn't be "subscribed" to every node server, only one instance of the fleet, right?  So isn't that a non-issue?

Comment: oh. hmm to think about it you're right. It's not a problem at all. Thanks!